# Tengo varios dropdown con el mismo ID en el xpath (SELENIUM)

Tags: java, selenium, test-ng, xpath

¿Qué debería hacer si tengo por ejemplo 2 dropdown, pero el nombre en el xpath es el mismo?

¿Cómo puedo hacer para identificarlos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

No hay name y los id son los mismos.
El código para ambos es este:

```
<input id="dropdown-input"
       class="form-control ng-pristine 
ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength"
       translate="" 
       translate-attr-placeholder="form.COUNTRY" 
       ng-model="dropdown.selectedText" 
       ng-click="dropdown.opened = true"
       ng-change="dropdown.opened = true"
       ng-focus="dropdown.opened = true"
       ng-keydown="$event.keyCode == 27 ? dropdown.opened = false : 0"
       ng-class="{'ng-invalid': filteredList.length == 0 && list.length > 0}"
       maxlength=""
       aria-invalid="false"
       placeholder="Country"
       style="background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+
Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-attachment: scroll;
           background-size: 16px 18px;
           background-position: 98% 50%;
/>
```

¿Cómo puedo yo identificar alguna diferencia entre estos dropdowns si son los mismos ids?

Comment: ¿podrías mostrar el HTML y el método que estás usando para seleccionar por XPath?

Comment: ¿No te basta con cambiar los `id` como te recomendé? También puedes probar a acceder a través de, por ejemplo, el atributo `translate-attr-placeholder` (si son diferentes).

Comment: Y, por cierto, si no hay atributo `name`, ¿qué te impide añadirlo?

Comment: No entiendo como puedo acceder a el atraves de ese atributo, si por lo general, uno puede acceder a un boton, label, un campo, por medio del xpath, id, class, linktext, etc, pero como hago yo para acceder por ahi? y gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: Gracias por agregar una parte de tu código @laura. En el código que publicaste, las comillas están mal. Además, claramente no es el mismo código para los 2 elementos. Por favor publicarlo a ambos, explicando por qué no se puede agregar algo en el código que los diferencie (sea un ido un name)

Comment: Mira, el problema está en que si ambos son exactamente iguales, entonces es IMPOSIBLE diferenciarlos, pero no pueden ser iguales porque uno pone "Country" y el otro "Currency", por lo que algo deben tener diferentes. Voy a modificar mi respuesta para mostrarte un ejemplo de cómo se pueden hacer búsquedas de diferentes campos (incluso de `id` que se repiten).

Comment: Si, tienen razon, es diferente, esa es la pequeña diferencia, que tienen esos dos placeholder diferentes, pero, entonces como especifico en la ruta del codigo eso, por ejemplo: public static By country = By.xpath(//*[@placeholder="Currency"]); ??

Answer (score 4):

Los `id` deben ser únicos. Si usas el mismo `id` para dar un mismo estilo CSS a varios elementos, deberías usar clases en su lugar.

[Aquí tienes algo más de información](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/id):

> La propiedad **Element.id** representa el identificador del elemento,
>   reflejando el atributo global de id.
>
> debe ser un único documento, y con frecuencia es utilizado para
>   recuperar el elemento usando [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Otros usos comunes de id
>   incluyen la utilización de elementos ID como un selector cuando se
>   está estilando el documento con CSS.

La traducción no es demasiado buena. En inglés dice "It must be unique in a document" que significa "debe ser único en un documento".

---

Edito: Voy a ver si con este ejemplo puedo ilustrarte en búsquedas basadas en otros atributos que no sea el `id`. Usaré XPath de JavaScript para facilitar la explicación.

```js
function pruebas() {
  console.log("Elementos con id 'dropdown-input': " +
    document.evaluate('count(//*[@id="dropdown-input"])', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).numberValue);
  console.log("Elementos con placeholder 'Currency': " +
    document.evaluate('count(//*[@placeholder="Currency"])', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).numberValue);
  var nodos = document.evaluate('//*[@id="dropdown-input"]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  for (var i = 0 ; i < nodos.snapshotLength; i++) {
    console.log("Placeholder del id 'dropdown-input' número " + i + ": " +
      nodos.snapshotItem(i).getAttribute('placeholder'));
  }
}

window.onload = pruebas;
```

```html
<input id="dropdown-input"
       class="form-control ng-pristine 
ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength"
       translate="" 
       translate-attr-placeholder="form.COUNTRY" 
       ng-model="dropdown.selectedText" 
       ng-click="dropdown.opened = true"
       ng-change="dropdown.opened = true"
       ng-focus="dropdown.opened = true"
       ng-keydown="$event.keyCode == 27 ? dropdown.opened = false : 0"
       ng-class="{'ng-invalid': filteredList.length == 0 && list.length > 0}"
       maxlength=""
       aria-invalid="false"
       placeholder="Country"
       style="background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+
Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-attachment: scroll;
           background-size: 16px 18px;
           background-position: 98% 50%;"
/>
<input id="dropdown-input"
       class="form-control ng-pristine 
ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength"
       translate="" 
       translate-attr-placeholder="form.CURRENCY" 
       ng-model="dropdown.selectedText" 
       ng-click="dropdown.opened = true"
       ng-change="dropdown.opened = true"
       ng-focus="dropdown.opened = true"
       ng-keydown="$event.keyCode == 27 ? dropdown.opened = false : 0"
       ng-class="{'ng-invalid': filteredList.length == 0 && list.length > 0}"
       maxlength=""
       aria-invalid="false"
       placeholder="Currency"
       style="background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+
Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-attachment: scroll;
           background-size: 16px 18px;
           background-position: 98% 50%;"
/>
```

Como puedes ver, la búsqueda XPath `//*[@id="dropdown-input"]` devuelve dos resultados, pero la búsqueda `//*[@placeholder="Currency"]` sólo devuelve uno.

He agregado un tercer ejemplo en el que busco todos los elementos con `//*[@id="dropdown-input"]` y enumero el contenido de su `placeholder`. Como puedes ver puedes hacer una búsqueda y que te devuelva más de un elemento como resultado. Basta entonces con recorrer los elementos para obtener sus datos.

Comment: Si, yo se, se supone que los id son unicos, pero me pasa que en unos dowpdown, el id es el mismo.

Comment: ¿Te refieres al `id` o a la ruta `xpath`? Son cosas diferentes. En tu comentario, cuya ruta es `//*[@id="comment-66240"]`, el `id` es único y el valor es `comment-66240`. Pon algún ejemplo para que sepa a qué llamas `id`.

Comment: Ya he visto la imagen que has subido. Debes cambiar el `id` de uno de los dos elementos. Si no puedes hacerlo porque la modificación del código HTML no está a tu alcance (no es tuya la web) dame la URL para que te dé una ruta alternativa a los elementos. Puedes llegar a uno u otro a través del padre o cualquier otro nodo ascendente, por ponerte un ejemplo.

Comment: Haz una cosa, busca por otro atributo de la etiqueta HTML que pueda diferenciarlos, por ejemplo el atributo `name`. Debería ser diferente en cada campo dentro de un mismo formulario. Sería algo como `//*[@name="nombre_campo"]`.

Comment: Me funciono perfecto con el placeholder, muchas gracias por su ayuda :)

Comment: Tengo otra duda al respecto, si es un select y un input al tiempo, como puedo hacer para que me coja las opciones del select? :(

Comment: Un elemento no puede ser de dos tipos al mismo tiempo. No entiendo tu pregunta.

Comment: Por cierto, si esta respuesta te sirvió de ayuda no olvides votarla como respuesta correcta, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Ahora no me toma los paises, puedo decir que esto si es igual por ejemplo, argentina y australia, esto es lo unico que los diferencia en el dropdown:

```
<li id="dropdown-list" class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-
if="!dropdown.isButton" ng-repeat="item in dropdown.list | 
filter:dropdown.selectedText as filteredList" ng-    
click="dropdown.clicked(item)" ng-keydown="$event.keyCode == 27 ? 
dropdown.opened = false : 0" role="button" tabindex="0">
AUSTRALIA 

<li id="dropdown-list" class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-
if="!dropdown.isButton" ng-repeat="item in dropdown.list | 
filter:dropdown.selectedText as filteredList" ng-
click="dropdown.clicked(item)" ng-keydown="$event.keyCode == 27 ? 
dropdown.opened = false : 0" role="button" tabindex="0" style="">
ARGENTINA
```

Comment: Te aconsejo no crear y borrar respuestas para aportar más información o hacer nuevas preguntas. A los que ayudamos en un tema no nos llega ningún tipo de notificación y se nos puede pasar por alto que lo has hecho. En este particular te recomiendo que abras un nuevo tema porque está más orientado a angularjs que a selenium y otro tema tratado en éste.

Comment: No es relacionado a angular, todo es selenium, para yo poder acceder a estos campos automaticamente tengo que mirar que datos coger para ponerlos en selenium, y lo de las respuestas, no las he borrado, solo que no me deja comentar mis propias publicaciones!

Comment: Entonces, si esta pregunta está resuelta marca como solución correcta la que veas conveniente y abre una nueva consulta. Estaré esperando para responderla y publicar código (en un comentario no se puede publicar código).